# BookStack Installation SQL Errors

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

I am setting up a [BookStack](https://www.bookstackapp.com/) instance on my local machine on wiki.localhost

My Server Environment is as follows;

- Windows 7 x64
- Apache 2.4.17 x86
- PHP 5.6.23 x86
- MariaDB 10.1.13 x86

This install is an instance of XAMPP v3.2.2, and I have Mod_Rewrite installed, enabled and working.

I have followed the installation instructions [here](https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/installation/), which require the following:

- Run Composer Install inside the directory to download dependencies
- copy /.env.example file in root to /.env and fill out MySQL and Mail Server details
- Ensure /storage, /bootstrap/cache, /public/uploads are all writable
- run php /artisian key:generate (artisian is a PHP file without the extension in the root dir)
- Set Document Root to /public directory
- Run php /artisian migrate

I have done all of these. An extra step, if not using apache or if htaccess is disabled, create my own rewrite rules, I have skipped because, as mentioned, I am running Apache with Mod_Rewrite enabled.

The problem that I am having now, is that while I should be able to access the website from my web browser now, I am being presented with the Laravel "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." page. I have set APP_DEBUG=true in my /.env file, and it gives me a much more descriptive error.

**1/2**
*PDOException in Connection.php line 333:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'system_name' in 'where clause'*

**2/2**
*QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'system_name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `system_name` = public limit 1)*

I have checked my database, and it has been set up and has an administrator record in my users table, but no system_name column.

Short of adding in the column myself or modifying the PHP with no idea what implications it may have further in the code, what can I do? I followed the install instructions to the letter (so I believe), and I would really like to get this project running rather than finding an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had experiences was due to an incomplete database creation.
To solve the problem, I dropped all tables and ran `php /artisan migrate` again.
The reason I experienced the problem may be that I closed the window too early when I had believed that it was complete when it in fact wasn't.

Comment: You can accept your answer to be the right answer. It will help the peopel who come on SO. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me the `php artisan migrate` command had failed due to insufficient user permissions. As Michael said, drop and recreate the database. Then make sure you run the migrations as a user with full permissions.